# Filter two data frames with the %in% operator in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, operators

EDIT: My question was closed with a reference to merge/join operators. The difference to a normal join is that I just want to keep the unmatched rows. How can I achieve this?

I want to filter this "df" for entries that are not in the "other_df" with R. For example this data table:
df:

| Person_ID | School | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2015 |
| 1 | B | 2015 |
| 1 | B | 2016 |

other_df:

| Person_ID | School | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2015 |
| 2 | A | 2017 |
| 1 | B | 2016 |

As a new df, I would like to receive this:

| Person_ID | School | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 2015 |
| 1 | B | 2016 |

```
df = df %>% filter(!(Person_ID %in% other_df$Person_ID & School %in% other_df$School 
                         & Year %in% other_df$Year))
```

This operation gives me an empty df... I think that is because the three conditions are not connected and every single one is in the "other_df", but I dont know how to do it properly.

As an addition I would have to add that there are more than these 3 columns, but I dont want to filter with them but still keep them.

Comment: You want an inner join: `dplyr::inner_join(dat1, dat2)`, or `merge(dat1, dat2)`

Comment: Use `dplyr`s `anti_join`: `anti_join(df, other_df)`.